# “Star Wars video game” VS “Video game of Star Wars”

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, idiomatic-language, phrase-choice, collocations

Can we say,

> “video game of Star Wars,” “book of Star Wars,” “movie of Star Wars” etc.

instead of

> “Star Wars video game,” “Star Wars book,” “Star Wars movie” etc?

For example, can we say these sentences

> Jedi Outcast is my favorite video game of Star Wars.

> I bought the new comic book of Star Wars.

instead of

> Jedi Outcast is my favorite Star Wars video game.

> I bought the new Star Wars comic book.

“Star Wars video game,” “Star Wars book,” “Star Wars movie” etc. sound more natural to me. I would like to receive your suggestion.

Comment: Related: [Why "The blog of Bill Gates" and not "The Bill Gates' blog"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/190167/9161)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, English often uses this construction to help nouns modify other nouns—giving the modifier first, with no "of" ("a Batman movie")—where other languages would use constructions equivalent to "a ___ of ___" (*una película de Batman*).

Using the construction you propose could be possible with a slight shift in meaning, since we use "of" to talk about parts of a whole. "The next episode **of** *Star Trek: Lower Decks*" means "the next episode to be added to the whole thing that is *Star Trek: Lower Decks*." This construction requires that the noun that comes after "of" be a specific thing that *has* parts. The Star Wars franchise is disparate enough that this doesn't work well; you could have "a new episode of *The Mandalorian*," but not "a new movie of Star Wars." (You could, though, use "franchise" or another word to refer to "all things having to do with Star Wars: "*The Last Jedi* is maybe the most divisive movie of the Star Wars saga.")

You could also use "___ of ___" to describe what a thing is "made of" or filled with, just like you would have a "glass of water." So you might say "I bought an old book of Ducktales comics." But this means "a book 'full of' Ducktales comics." You couldn't say "I bought a new comic book of Star Wars," since "Star Wars" isn't really a *thing*, but you could say "I bought a new book of Star Wars comics," since "comics" are a "thing," and "Star Wars" is the type of comics. (And again, it would be less idiomatic to say "comics of Star Wars.")

Answer (score -1):

"The video game Star Wars is a lot of fun."   [appositional]
OR
"The Star Wars video game is a lot of fun". [naming the game]

The "of" is completely out because **there is no possession.**

- A book of mine on this issue. [I either own the book on it or I wrote the book]
- A movie of his on this issue. [He directed the  movie. It is "his movie".]

Comment: I started out with an answer similar to this but I think the issue of possession in this case is a bit more convoluted.  We can say *A movie of Spielberg's* and that shows that this movie is part of what we consider to belong to him, part of his *oervre*.   Does *movie of Star War's* work in a similar way?  It belongs to the Star Wars universe.  Perhaps it's not an issue of possession but of expression?

Comment: @EllieK A movie of Spielberg's is not the same thing at all. In fact, he is the "possessor" of the movie.

Comment: sigh - there's no reasoning with you.  Spielberg no more possesses Jaws, than the Star Wars franchise possesses Phantom Menace.  You failed to engage my point and instead provided a response as brief and unenlightening as your answer.

Comment: @EllieK Tsk, tsk, tsk. We just don't say: The movie of Stars Wars, do we? We say in "apposition": The movie [called] Star Wars, like "The book [called] Gone with the Wind" OR it is a name: The Star Wars video game. A movie of Spielberg's takes an apostrophe s because he is the director; it is his, so to speak.

Comment: @AnonFNV They are two different FORMS for naming the game; one is appositional and the other is works like a noun.

Comment: @Lambie - Thank you for engaging.  The point I make is that what we **say** has nothing to do with **possession**.  Possession vs Expression.

Comment: @EllieK It does. That is WHY we don't say: The movie of Star Wars: Star Wars does not own the movie. That movie of Spielberg's, i,e. His movie. He would be seen to own it or possess it. Just like: A car of mine.

Comment: @Lambie I see. You wrote [naming the game] like it only applies to the second sentence, which I found confusing. I still think OP is using 'The Star Wars video game' to mean a game from the Star Wars franchise, not a game called Star Wars. But I'll delete my comment. Also I think EllieK is right about the Star Wars franchise being a possessor in that case.

Comment: @Lambie - *A book of mine on this issue. [I either own the book on it or I wrote the book].*  Or you edited the book, or it's on your favorite book list, or you were the illustrator, or your publishing company published it.  Possession is much broader than *I wrote it* or *it's on my bookshelf*.  Which is where my hesitation to call this an issue of possession arose.

Comment: @EllieK A book of mine on this issue means: Obviously, if you talking and are a publisher, and say: A book of ours on this issue means you publishing company IN EFFECT owns it.

Comment: No.  It means your publishing company *published* it.  Stepping out here.  Last word.

Answer (score -1):

No, you cannot say "___ is my favorite video game of Star Wars" the same way you can't say "___ is my favorite book of Harry Potter/movie of the Avengers/album of Taylor Swift". The closest you could get, I think, would be saying "____ is my favorite of the Star Wars video games", which would still be slightly awkward (perhaps) but totally acceptable. I personally am not on board with the previous lamb-based answer to this question. I think "of" works badly in this context except! if you are using a word that is by definition a piece of a larger whole - "chapter of", "episode of", "installment of" would all work better. Otherwise you have to use the category (or whatever it is) as an adjective.

Comment: This is wrong.  You do quite often hear people say these things  as describrd in the other answers

Comment: I don't think I'm necessarily fully right, but I don't think I'm fully wrong. I think it is slipperier. You could say any of these things but I think it would strike me as off.